# firebase_storage object-not-found No object exists at the desired reference flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**Important**: I found the same question but it is closed with incomplete debugging information.

I am uploading an image to firebase storage and then getting the download URL of that image and storing it to firebase so I can use that URL to show the User's profile image using network image.

It was working fine before when I was storing the image like

```
Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images');
      file = await _compressImage(file: file,);
      await storageRef.putFile(file);
      final String downloadUrl = await storageRef.child(id).getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
```

but after I am storing images in specific folders

```
Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images');
      file = await _compressImage(file: file, id: id);
      await storageRef
          .child(Get.find<UserController>().user.username)
          .child(id)
          .putFile(file);
      final String downloadUrl = await storageRef.child(id).getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
```

it is showing this error.

```
 [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

**Here is the explainable code:**
I am storing downloadable URL in newImage variable

```
 String newImage;
      if (_controller.file != null) {
        newImage = await Database().uploadFile(
            file: _controller.file,
            id: Get.find<UserController>().user.username);
        print("new image: " + newImage.toString());
      }
```

But here when I am printing newImage's value it is printing *null* to console.

```
new image: null
```

Here is the second method to upload image to firebase storage.

```
Future<String> uploadFile({@required File file, @required String id}) async {
    try {
      file = await _compressImage(file: file, id: id);
      await storageRef
          .child(Get.find<UserController>().user.username)
          .child(id)
          .putFile(file);
      final String downloadUrl = await storageRef.child(id).getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Debug Console:

```
E/StorageException(11376): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(11376): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(11376):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(11376): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11376): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(11376):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:76)
E/StorageException(11376):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
E/StorageException(11376):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
E/StorageException(11376):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
I/flutter (11376): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
I/flutter (11376): new image: null
```

But when I check the firebase storage and the image is uploaded successfully there.

What I know is that image is successfully uploading to firebase storage but the above method somehow returning a downable URL before uploading the image.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was a bit unexpected.
First, I had the code like this which is how many examples have it.

```
  Reference reference = storage.ref(filePath);

  UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageToUpload);

  final storageSnapshot = uploadTask.snapshot;

  final downloadUrl = await storageSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Then, I decided to play around with it.
I notice if I await the putFile call, it changes the return type, even though its not a future.

```
  Reference reference = storage.ref(filePath);

  final TaskSnapshot snapshot = await reference.putFile(imageToUpload);

  final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

And what do you know, this worked! Very odd, considering it's not obvious you can await the putFile call.

Comment: This should be accepted! Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 3):

here's how we do it

```
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('user_Image')
        .child('${authResult.user?.uid}.jpg');
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageUser);
    final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);

    final urlImageUser = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Answer (score 2):

please refer below code for uploading images to firebase,

```
Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images/${imagePath.path.split('/').last}');
    // UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imagePath);
    await storageReference.putFile(imagePath);
    //TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String downloadURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
    print('File Uploaded: $downloadURL');
    return downloadURL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I lost many hours with the same problem as you and IDK why but it is working by creating the reference before using it:

```
    final FirebaseStorage feedStorage =
              FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: F.feedBucket);
    
          Reference refFeedBucket = feedStorage
              .ref()
              .child('venues')
              .child(auth.user.uid)
              .child('vibes')
              .child(p.basename(file.path));

  String downloadUrl;

  TaskSnapshot uploadedFile = await refFeedBucket.putFile(file);

  if (uploadedFile.state == TaskState.success) {
    downloadUrl = await refFeedBucket.getDownloadURL();
  }

  return downloadUrl;
```

Comment: i also searching for same solution ., but above solution somehow not work for me ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this
for loading image from firebase

```
 Future<String> downloadedUrl(String imageName) async {
    String downloadedUrl =
        await storage.ref('$imageName').getDownloadURL();
    return downloadedUrl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the capitalization of words case wrong on my path.

The Firebase storage is `Case sensitive`

check it, please!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding here, this problem here is that

```
final String downloadUrl = await storageRef.child(id).getDownloadURL();
```

is hit before completing the uploading file task and as result, it returns an exception that,

```
firebase_storage object-not-found No object exists at the desired reference flutter
```

If we go through all the functions of the `Storage` we've another method that can help us to know does the task is completed or not it's future we can add await and then hit then the `getDownloadURL` to get the URL.

```
    try {
          String name = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + file.name;
          Reference reference = _firebaseStorage.ref(FirebaseKey.images).child(name);
          final metadata = SettableMetadata(
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': file.path},
          );
          UploadTask task;
          if (kIsWeb) {
            task = reference.putData(await file.readAsBytes(), metadata);
          } else {
            task = reference.putFile(File(file.path), metadata);
          }
    
/// wait for task completion
          TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await task.whenComplete(() => {debugPrint('Task completed')});


          return taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        } on FirebaseException catch (e, stackTrace) {
          debugPrint('Exception: on $e $stackTrace');
          rethrow;
        } catch (e, stackTrace) {
          debugPrint('Exception: catch $e $stackTrace');
          rethrow;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create the specific folder in Firebase Storage and allow read/write access to it.

Here is a sample rule, that worked for me:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profile_pictures/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time in resolving this query myself and actually the solution to this turned out to to be pretty simple.

I just had to "await" a few requests I had sent earlier for storing image to firebase storage.

Also, awaiting the getdownloadurl() mehtod is also necessary.

Here's the before and after sample code

- **Before**:

  ```
   final firebaseimageupload = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('user_images').child('${userCredentials.user!.uid}.jpg');  

       firebaseimageupload.putFile(_selectedimage!);

       final imageurl = firebaseimageupload.getDownloadURL();
  ```
- **After:**

final firebaseimageupload = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('user_images').child('${userCredentials.user!.uid}.jpg');

```
        await firebaseimageupload.putFile(_selectedimage!);

        final imageurl = await firebaseimageupload.getDownloadURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't start the storage in Firebase Console and bang head for 2 days searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, which occurred unexpectedly for some of my users, always under the same conditions: poor network connectivity or being located far from my server location.

I discovered the reason. It was due to the "Resize Images" Firebase extension being used in my project. This caused the resize trigger to delete the file before my client could download the URL after the file had been uploaded.

If you are facing a similar situation, set the deleteOriginalFile option to false.